# why ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush is not working for button

Tags: xaml, button, xamarin.winphone

Whenever I press and hold the button I can see a blue color background till I release the button

I tried to reset it white by using the key *ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush*

Here is my button code

```
                <Button Content="Submit" BorderThickness="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="21"  Height="85" BorderBrush="White" Command="{Binding testCommand}" Foreground="{StaticResource Green}">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
```

But its not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the brush in your application resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />
</Application.Resources>
```

This will change the button press background for ALL buttons however. If you want specific buttons to have different backgrounds, you'll need to edit the `Button` template for each. One simple way to do that is to define a style for each and set the `Background` to whatever you like during the `IsPressed` Trigger

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Style has BasedOn,Setters,TargetType properties but it doesn't have triggers